# Curl + Invoke RestMethod

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, blockchain, pycurl

So I'm working on a blockchain project and the code itself has been fixed to where it doesn't give me errors. It tells me "Running on xyz"

That said, when I go to PowerShell and run the `Invoke-WebRequest` as others have mentioned previously (instead of curl) I get the error:

```
PS C:\Users\sebt1> Invoke-WebRequest "localhost:5000/txion" \ -H "Content-Type: 
    application/json" \ -d '{"from": "akjflw", "to":"fjlakdj", "amount": 3}'
```

> Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert
>   the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type "System.String" to
>   type
>
> "System.Collections.IDictionary". At line:1 char:47
>   + ...  "localhost:5000/txion" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -d '{ ...
>   +                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following instead:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost:5000/txion" -Method POST -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "application/json"} -body @{"from" = "akjflw"; "to" = "fjlakdj"; "amount" = 3}
```

Or:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost:5000/txion" -Method POST -Content-Type "application/json" -body @{"from" = "akjflw"; "to" = "fjlakdj"; "amount" = 3}
```

Comment: The first method gave me a "Method Not Allowed for the requested url" but also gave me this error on python shell that is running my code. I'm going to double check the original code and try this again. Thanks 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 11:33:03] "GET /txion?amount=3&from=akjflw&to=fjlakdj HTTP/1.1" 405 - –

Comment: Are you trying to post? If so, you will need to add `-Method POST`.

Comment: Got it thanks! It works and now I my interview will go solid. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) makes this simple. The response is automatically loaded into a `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` for you.

```
Invoke-RestMethod localhost:5000/txion -Method Post -Body @{"from": "akjflw"; "to":"fjlakdj"; "amount": 3; }
```

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod worked for me for posting xml loaded from a text file, with some tweaks